# How to check if I'm using a proxy?

Tags: proxy

I'm running chromium on Linux outside of any desktop environment. I have set `auto_proxy` but I'm not fully sure if it actually works properly. How can I check this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try some online service as http://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-check